# can anyone help me to solve the error::: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /localhost/braintree/app.php on line 14

Tags: php

```
<?php

require_once 'braintree-php-2.14.0/lib/Braintree.php';
require_once __DIR__ . 'silex/vendor/autoload.php';
Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('...');
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('...');
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('...');
$app = new Silex\Application();
$app->get('/', function () {
    include 'views/form.php';
});
$app->run();
//$app->get("/braintree-php-2.14.0", function () {
$app->get("/braintree", function () {
   include 'views/response.php';
});
?>
```

this is braintree payments system i read the documentation clearly but not solved.error is found in this line 14:   $app->get("/braintree", function () {

Comment: Unless the merchantid/publickey/privatekey you posted up there are fake/devel versions, you'd better go get some new ones issued, because you've just plastered them across the interwebitubes for everyone to use.

Comment: Are you certain that is the only error, and are you certain about the line? I ask because older PHP versions didn't have anonymous functions, but it should have choked here: `$app->get('/', function () {`

Comment: i have php version 5.3 on my localhost and in my server php version is 5.2.

Comment: @Shan - that's the problem then. The embedded function syntax you're using on that line is only valid from PHP 5.3 upward. You need to upgrade your server.

Comment: (ps - please don't say "I can't upgrade my server. PHP 5.2 has been end of life and unsupported for nearly two years already; anyone still running PHP 5.2 is exposing themselves to risk; you need to have the latest version in order to have all the security patches)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that anonymous functions are only available in PHP 5.3+. If at all possible I'd suggest upgrading your server to the newest version of PHP available, 5.4.7.

Another issue might be that you're calling $app->run() before you add the response hook, so I'd move the run() call to the end.

If you can't upgrade PHP then the following fix should work:

```
<?php
require_once 'braintree-php-2.14.0/lib/Braintree.php';
require_once __DIR__ . 'silex/vendor/autoload.php';
Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('...');
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('...');
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('...');
$app = new Silex\Application();
function form() {
  include 'views/form.php';
}
$app->get('/', form);
function response() {
  include 'views/response.php';
}
$app->get("/braintree", response);
$app->run();
?>
```

The other reason I really like PHP 5.4 is that it [includes a lightweight (ie not for production) server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) that makes testing and debugging a lot easier. I'm a Braintree dev and wrote the guide this came from so I hope this helps!